# What is the different between localhost:4200 and localhost:4200/projectName?

Tags: angular

I use angular v6. When I run `ng server`. The `localhost:4200/projectName` can open the project. But It not update automatically when I update codes.

So I want to know what is it and where it's source code? I'm not use `ng build --prod`.

Answer (score 1):

ng serve is a command provided by the [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki).

The Angular CLI is a tool to initialize, develop, scaffold and maintain Angular applications. 
ng serve builds the application and starts a web server.

If you want to update and reload the DOM as soon as you update code and save the file use:-

```
ng serve --watch
```

And also if you want to specify the host and port from which you want to access your angular application use:-

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200
```